# Qt Quick Controls 2 hangs when overwriting Button.qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to [implement my own style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#creating-a-custom-style) and for this I want to override the built-in objects. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// main.cpp
QQuickStyle::setStyle("mystyle");
```

and

```
// mystyle/Button.qml
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1 as Controls

Controls.Button {
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "green"
    }
}
```

and

```
// qml.qrc
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>mystyle/CheckBox.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

According to the docs I believe this should work automagically [using file selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-fileselectors.html).

However, my app hangs on startup. My guess is that I fall into a recursive import. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: I might have found the answer here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/76704/subtyping-the-default-type-in-a-theme-controls-2/3 If that's true, then my undertaking is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Qt Quick Controls 2 styling system is based on QML type registration. When you run your app with *mystyle*, the type known as QtQuick.Controls.Button **IS** `mystyle/Button.qml`. Therefore `mystyle/Button.qml` cannot inherit QtQuick.Controls.Button. It cannot inherit itself.

This is basically the same as writing the following C++:

```
// button.h
#include "button.h"
class Button : public Button {};
```

A bit radicalized, but easy to understand analogy. :)

What you can do is to have `(My)Button.qml` somewhere, let it inherit QtQuick.Controls.Button, and don't register it as a Qt Quick Controls 2 but simply import the folder. This is what we call as "[Customizing Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html)".

Comment: Having said that, the QML engine definitely should thrown an error instead of hanging, and we should cover this in the Qt Quick Controls 2 styling documentation. You're not the first one to attempt this. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The style must be configured before loading QML that imports Qt Quick Controls.It is not possible to change the style after the QML types have been registered. [setStyle()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickstyle.html#setStyle)
2. Apply the existing style in your custom style's qml files.

Note: It is recommended to use QQmlApplicationEngine, which internally creates a QQmlFileSelector instance. This is all that is needed to take QML file selectors into use.

See: [Creating Custom Styles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#creating-a-custom-style)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This part works correctly after I removed the `+` in front of the style name, I think that must be a mistake in the docs. I just updated the question with my knowledge about the problem. Seems like I don't know how to import the default style for extension.